# Change icon of specific files in windows like dropbox

Tags: java, windows, winapi, icons

I am working on an app which needs to process files and send data from the client to the server (for a specific folder). I want the app to be able to add a small tick like the ones on the dropbox (green tick for synced and blue for syncing).

for folders i figured i could use the desktop.ini file. Am unable to figure out a mechanism to work with files especially when i dont have a limited set of formats which may be dropped in the directory which i am watching....

In essence i am trying to replicate dropbox's icon change mechanism during syncing of files..

I am using java right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [overlay icons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144123%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in a shell extension but I don't know about the feasability of doing this in Java.

See [these results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=windows+shell+overlay+icon) for more examples and information.